# getBoundingClientRect returns incorrect results

Tags: javascript, html, webkit, android-webview

I'm using the getBoundingClientRect() to determine the absolute left offset of the element on the page.

The page is split into columns:

```
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
-webkit-column-width: 720px;
```

And the JS function is:

```
function findAnchorOffset(anchorId) {
    anchor = document.getElementById("res" + anchorId);
    if (anchor != null) {
        var rect = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log("Rect: " + rect.left);
    } else {
        console.log("Anchor offset not found!");
    }
}
```

The function works, but the rect.left is about twice less then it should be.
For example, it returns 5902.9146, but in fact the left offset is about 11000. Why?

**UPD**. If I change the JS function like this, it returns correct offset:

```
function findAnchorOffset(anchorId) {
    anchor = document.getElementById("res" + anchorId);
    if (anchor != null) {
        var rect = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();
        console.log("Rect: " + rect.left * 2);
    } else {
        console.log("Anchor offset not found!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way we can test it out ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I think it's a pretty difficult, because it's a part of ePub reader that is implemented in Android WebView with couple of changes in HTML, but I'll try to copy-paste the resulting HTML from Chrome Remote Debugging.

Comment: Is it scrolled  at all or because that will affect results and aside from that I'd need to see a visual representation and or a code breakdown of the html css rendering